# Entity constructor gives "incompatible types" error

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio, android-room

So, to give a little bit of context, I am currently developing an app with a database. By doing research it became clear that Room from Google (Which uses SQLite) was the way to go. So I have my database fully set up, with foreign keys, and also `@Transaction`'s (which stands for 1 to many or one to one relationship).

Currently, I have been stuck on something for a whole day:
Whenever I try to create a constructor for an entity (table), if there is something else than a String as a parameter, it gives me the `incompatible types: <null> cannot be converted to int` error. (or float or double etc.).

I just can't figure out why this happens, also tried removing all foreign keys and trying with as little code as possible, but it just does not work.

FYI: the error occurs in a generated class. This class is generated from your DAO interface (DatabaseAccessInterface), which is where you list all your Query functions, including your relationships. The generated class than calls the constructor of the relating entity : `_tmpFan = new Fan(null,null,null,null,null,null,_tmpCreatedAt);` like this, than says `incompatible types: <null> cannot be converted to int`

Has anyone come across this error before, or do you just have to stick to Strings?
If you need to know a part of my code, simply ask, and I will provide it. (It would be quite a lot of code to post it all in one post, but I will post some fragments below)

Transaction / relation inside interface:

```
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM measurement_session WHERE fan_id = :fanID")
public List<FansWithMeasureSessions> getMeasureSessionsOfFan(int fanID);
```

Fan class:

```
@Entity (tableName = "fan",
        foreignKeys = {
                @ForeignKey(entity = MeasurementSession.class,
                        parentColumns = "fan_id",
                        childColumns = "fan_id",
                        onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE)
        },
        indices = {
                @Index(value = "customer_id", unique = true)
        }
        )
public class Fan {

    @ColumnInfo(name = "customer_id")
    public int customerID;

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "fan_id")
    public int fanID;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "fan_name")
    public String fanName;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "fan_type")
    public String fanType;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "diameter")
    public float diameter;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "length")
    public float length;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "width")
    public float width;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "created_at")
    @TypeConverters(DateConverter.class)
    public Date createdAt;

    public Fan(int customerID, String fanName, String fanType, float diameter, float length, float width, Date createdAt) {
        this.customerID = customerID;
        this.fanName = fanName;
        this.fanType = fanType;
        this.diameter = diameter;
        this.length = length;
        this.width = width;
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }
}
```

FansWithMeasureSessions class:

```
public class FansWithMeasureSessions {
    @Embedded public Fan fan;
    @Relation(
            entity = MeasurementSession.class,
            parentColumn = "fan_id",
            entityColumn = "fan_id"
    )
    public List<MeasurementSession> measurementSessions;
}
```

Commented out most of my other code, while still maintaining the error, so this should do!

Comment: Avoid using non-nullable primitive types for IDs, since they need to be able to hold the value of "not set". Use `Integer` instead of `int`.

Comment: I just decided to completely abandon constructors, but this is a good tip! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

Use nullable types for `float`, `int`, `double` etc.
This means that you instead should use `Float`, `Integer`, `Double` datatypes (which are nullable)